# How to load php code into html tag DIV using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to load php code into div tag to show the results but the below code doesn't work for.

Can anyone please help me...to resolve this

my code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function()
{ 
   $("#myDiv").load("refreshing.php");      
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id='myDiv'> </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console. Use this code to check for error:

`$( "#myDiv" ).load( "refreshing.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#myDiv" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});`

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: can you check that you set the correct url for refreshing.php if it in your site root it sould be something like this "/refreshing.php" and check your console for errors

Comment: You were missing the `);`

Answer (score 1):

Change script tag to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
   $("#myDiv").load("refreshing.php");      
});
</script>
```

i.e. you're missing `);` at the end

Also, `document` should not have quotes on it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load php code .load() because as the web server gets the GET request with .php, the request is passed to PHP interpreter which will execute the PHP script and return the result of the php script instead of code. So what you can do is in your PHP script, do a echo of all the code that you want to display. Or, you can define custom rule in your Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten the closing bracket:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#myDiv").load("refreshing.php");
});
```